# Can i call other gui on python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

How can i call other gui when click button?
Here is run first gui so directly show me other gui not clicked button

--------------------------------------first gui:----------------------------

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from other import Window


class Windows(QMainWindow):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    self.InitUI()

def InitUI(self):

    self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
    self.setGeometry(200, 200, 600, 500)

    self.button = QPushButton("Insert Data", self)
    self.button.setGeometry(100, 250, 100, 30)
    self.button.clicked.connect(self.Open)

    self.show()

def Open(self):
    self.notepad = Window()
    self.notepad.show()

App = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Windows()
sys.exit(App.exec())
```

----------------------other gui:-----------------------

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QStatusBar


class Window(QMainWindow):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    self.InitUI()

def InitUI(self):

    self.statusBar().showMessage("This is a simple Status bar")

    self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
    self.setGeometry(200, 200, 600, 500)
    self.show()


App = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Window()
sys.exit(App.exec())
```

Answer (score 0):

other gui.py:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QStatusBar


class Window(QMainWindow):
   def __init__(self):
       super().__init__()

       self.InitUI()

   def InitUI(self):

       self.statusBar().showMessage("This is a simple Status bar")

       self.setWindowTitle('GUI')
       self.setGeometry(200, 200, 600, 500)
```

first gui doesn't need to be chnged

Comment: When i run first gui, just show me other gui not showing first gui and not clicked button

Comment: @ChukaB How come can you try it again, *Note: the code i posted is the whole code already for other gui.py*

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your code by this:

```
from notepad import notepad
self._new_window = notepad()
self._new_window.showMaximized()
self.hide()
```

Comment: problem not solved.